# QT version issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have installed QT in Ubuntu 20.04 using the following command:

```
sudo apt install build-essentials
sudo apt install qt5creator
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

This results in QT Creator version 4.11.0, based on Qt 5.12.8.

Now I have made a small desktop application using it and I can run that application too. I have built the application both in debug mode and release mode and trying to run on a system that has qt version 5.9.5. But I am getting that the system cannot locate qt 5.12. I cannot update the target system so please suggest a way to install the qt 5.9.5 kit in my current machine where I am building the application.

Moreover, I have looked up multiple places to install the qt 5.9.5 kit but it seems to suggest to use the QT Maintenance tool kit. But in Linux, I cannot find that as well. In /opt/ I cannot locate the maintenance tool kit. Even with the following command

```
locate tool | grep qt
```

I am unable to locate any qt maintenance tool kit.

**Note I need the open source version of it.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming one. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/820054/selecting-qt5-using-qtchooser

Comment: sorry I didn't know that we cannot ask a non-programming question here. By the way, the link that you provided wasn't the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't develop against a more recent Qt version and then run the app using an older version.

You should uninstall Qt Creator, and then download the Qt Online Installer:

https://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/

Run it:

```
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
```

(You might need to register for a Qt account first, as the installer needs a login.)

In the installer, install Creator and the needed Qt versions you want to develop against.

Another approach is to make an AppImage out of your application, which will bundle the Qt libraries you're using. For the AppImage to be compatible with most Linux distros, it's recommended to build on the oldest still supported Ubuntu LTS version (16.04 right now.) You can install the latest Qt version there (5.15) and then create an AppImage of your app.

Binary software distribution on Linux is not trivial. It's quite tedious so you usually need to automate it. For example using docker images and/or a CI service like GitHub Actions or Travis CI.

Comment: thanks @Nikos C for the answer. downloading the qt installer and then reinstalling qt creator with the required packages really helped

Comment: "You can't develop against a more recent Qt version and then run the app using an older version." - However the reverse is not the case in that the libraries are generally forward compatible to some extent (minor and patch number increments) in that an application built and linked against an older Qt can still be run when those shared libraries have been updated.

For checking your application can refer to `QT_VERSION_STR` for the compilation version and `qVersion()` for the run-time version!